# How to import arranged .csv file in r

Tags: r

I want to import the .csv file into a data frame.

I already tried to import but the whole file data come under only one column.

```r
    db <- read.csv("sample.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ',')
```

```
> db
                                                          V1
1    T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1234,0
2     T,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1235,0
3      T,SBIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103032,1236,0
4 P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1237,1234
5  P,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1238,1235
6    T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1239,0
7    T,.CITIBANK,1000,101,20121210,120,20121209103036,1240,0
8 P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1241,1234
9 P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1242,1239
> str(db)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 9 levels "P,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1238,1235",..: 7 6 9 2 1 8 5 3 4
```

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce your error, but you can split that one column to multiples using this syntax: `db <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(db$V1),',')))`

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of the CSV? Maybe it has quotes at the start and end of each line? Or maybe something else is weird with it?

Comment: @Gregor - I had the same idea but just tested with test data when you posted.

Comment: T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1234,0
T,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1235,0
T,SBIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103032,1236,0
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1237,1234
P,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1238,1235
T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1239,0
T,.CITIBANK,1000,101,20121210,120,20121209103036,1240,0
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1241,1234
P,ICICIBANK,1100,100,20121210,120,20121209103035,1242,1239

Comment: Please avoid writing input data in comments. It is better to edit the question and insert the input data there. FYI - please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score -1):

Import with CSV data file shown below causes the error. As you can see, this is the problem. In a first attempt without quotes I could not reproduce the error.

Please clean up your input data and **delete the quotes** to solve the problem.

**Data for error test case only:**

```
"T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1234,0"
"T,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1235,0"
"T,SBIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103032,1236,0"

db <- read.csv("test-case.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ',')
head (db)
                                                          V1
1    T,ICICIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103030,1234,0
2     T,AXISBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103031,1235,0
3      T,SBIBANK,1000,100,20121210,120,20121209103032,1236,0
```

Comment: There are no quotes in my data.